# WAMP virtualhost wont redirect

Tags: apache, wamp, virtualhost

Ok I had to move my web to a new host. However new one is running Win 7 ultimate instead of 2008 R2.

To make sure i wont forget something moved over the existing WAMP Apache/PHP versions (bin folders).

It all works fine, except that `virtualhosts`  simply wont redirect  to the new `documentroot`.

it includes the virtualhosts conf file.

> NameVirtualHost 88.159.116.217:90 should redirect to
>   C:/wamp/www/update/  but instead still directs to C:/wamp/www/

This setup worked fine on the 2008 R2. But now its simply ignoring everything defined in the included `vhost.conf`.
No errors (except that if my software connects to 88.159.116.217:90 - the files are not found since its root folder instead of update).

Code:

```
ServerAdmin hidden
ServerName hidden

DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/update/"
CustomLog logs/rfpatch.log combined
ErrorLog logs/rfpatch_err.log

<Directory "C:/wamp/www/update/">

    Options -Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks IncludesNoExec
    AllowOverride None
    AddOutputFilter Includes html
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    AddType application/zip .tmp
    AddType application/zip .cab

    <Files update.dll>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .dll
    </Files>

</Directory>
```

I don't need a hosts file  - I'm not using domains.
There is no admin access problem (uac is also disabled).
the included vhost conf file is loaded - but vhost definitions are ignored.

The Apache version is the same as it was in the 2008 R2 server.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of two things...

1. You've not restarted Apache. It needs to be restarted for configuration changes to take effect.
2. Your Browser is caching the old page... Close all browser windows and tabs, then open the page and press CTRL-F5 to do a hard refresh. Also try clearing the browser cache data, it sometime "remembers" redirects and uses them over and over.